# How do I apply an opacity gradient on a UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, opacity

I would like my UIView to fade from 100% opacity to 0% opacity. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Comment: Is its background dynamically-rendered, or a static background image?

Comment: Its on some text: https://skitch.com/sidwynkoh/rkxar/main.psd-66.7-other-results-layer-mask-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the view, together with its labels, is sitting on some static background image or color, a quick and dirty trick is to create gradient PNGs of that image or color and place them over the view.

Otherwise, see if you can adapt [this `CALayer` gradient mask solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306043/uiview-border-with-fade-or-blur-effect/2348337#2348337) for your view.

Answer (score 3):

[Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2079/core-graphics-101-shadows-and-gloss) has a great tutorial on setting gradients for objects.  My suggestion is to modify the following code to suit your needs.

```
//Ray's code:
void drawLinearGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor, 
    CGColorRef  endColor) {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)startColor, (id)endColor, nil];

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, 
        (CFArrayRef) colors, locations);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```