# Make bottom part of UITextField(UIScrollView) transparent

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Here's a good example that sums it up:

[image]

This is a `UITextField` that contains long text, so the user is able to scroll down to view the rest of the text.

How can I make the bottom rows appear "transparent"?

`UITextField` only allows setting global text properties (like color, font size, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to create a CALayer containing a gradient and use it as mask layer of your UIView's layer (alpha values of the mask layer will be used.) see this answer:
 [UIView border with fade or blur effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306043/uiview-border-with-fade-or-blur-effect/2348337#2348337)

Answer (score 0):

[This will help you.](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fadingtextview)Not sure but some functionality like you want.

Hope this helps you.

All the best !!!

Comment: Thanks but this is good only when having solid background color